# I am trying to connect to wifi using wpa_cli set_network command,but it always returns FAIL

Tags: wifi, wpa-cli

```
krishna@krishna-PC:~/Downloads/wificonnect1$ sudo wpa_cli scan

[sudo] password for krishna: 

Selected interface 'wlan0'

OK

krishna@krishna-PC:~/Downloads/wificonnect1$ sudo wpa_cli scan_results

Selected interface 'wlan0'

bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
fc:0a:81:1d:6d:80   2412    -43 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    econsys
00:24:01:ba:b4:65   2437    -72 [WPA-PSK-TKIP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP][WPS][ESS] Test
6c:72:20:f2:1a:6b   2412    -60 [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]  Hari
c0:ee:fb:31:ec:4a   2447    -76 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    Vishal's hotspot
fc:0a:81:1c:6d:f0   2412    -61 [WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]    econsys
c4:12:f5:08:10:70   2427    -63 [WPA-PSK-CCMP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP][ESS]  GoGreen
f4:f2:6d:6d:23:44   2462    -62 [WPS][ESS]  joyglobal

krishna@krishna-PC:~/Downloads/wificonnect1$ sudo wpa_cli add_network

Selected interface 'wlan0'

1

krishna@krishna-PC:~/Downloads/wificonnect1$ sudo wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid "econsys"

Selected interface 'wlan0'
FAIL
```

How should I connect?

Answer (score 19):

Create a `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file with the following lines:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

Run:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Type:

```
wpa_cli
```

then:

```
scan
scan_results
add_network
```

sample output:

```
0
```

select the SSID (replace `0` with the exact output):

```
set_network 0 ssid "Your SSID here"
```

Set your password :

```
set_network 0 psk "You Password here"
```

Without the double quotes the command will `FAIL`.
Next step:

```
enable_network 0
```

then:

```
save_config
quit
```

Without the interactive commands you should use (single quote added):

```
sudo wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid '"econsys"'
```

or

```bsh
sudo wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid "\"econsys\""
```

instead of:

```
sudo wpa_cli set_network 1 ssid "econsys"
```

The single quote should be added too when adding your password:

```
sudo wpa_cli set_network 1 psk '"Your Password"'
```

Comment: Still after following the steps, "save_config" returns FAIL.

Comment: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
Delete '/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan1' manually if it is not used anymore
Failed to initialize control interface '/run/wpa_supplicant'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

Comment: @roizpi Run `killall wpa_supplicant` then try again.

Comment: I use the command, but still get same error trace

Comment: Fixed the network, altough not by using `wpa_cli`. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: @another, can you let us know what was your issue? I run into the same error, and try to see what would be possible reason.

Comment: @bizi What I remember is that I was setting up an IoT device, and I ended up configuring it with "/etc/network/interfaces" successfully. I didn't resolve the issue itself, but found another way to do it. Also I remember reflashing the SD card and starting over again. Either of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: Note that in the command `set_network 0 ssid "Your SSID here"`, the double quotes must be included

Answer (score 3):

To add a new network, without interactive command,

And then,

```
sudo wpa_cli add_network
```

To set ssid and Password for the new network, eg: ssid: mynetwork , password: 123456789

For SSID,go to the [hexa code](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html)

Type your ssid name and convert to HEX code (choose without space).

```
sudo wpa_cli add_network ssid 1 "6d796e6574776f726b"
```

For psk , go to  [PSK Generator](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html) and type ssid name in "SSID" and password in
"Passphrase" column and click generate PSK. (This is secure , dont need to worry about giving credentials)

```
sudo wpa_cli add_network 1 psk "26eb897d8abf5fa4649b77736b03fd544161ee41c85066ee0a5b233ad3650bd3"
```

This is the only method will work when you try to set a network outside of interactive mode. Have tried giving credentials directly , always fails.

And if save_config fails, try this one

```
sudo wpa_cli reassociate 1
```

Comment: You can use`wpa_passphrase "ssid" passphrase` to generate the psk.